# Python Tkinter GUI program: SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm not new to python or programing in general, but am still learning with python. I am working on a program for me and some of my friends. and I was making the GUI, and code, for the login screen, when I kept getting this syntax error for one of my functions. And I have no idea as to what may be causing it. If someone could provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated. p.s. I'll only be posting the part I've been having an error with, and only what is, or that I feel, is necessary to help show what's going on, and I'm using python 3.x if that helps.

```
# Login Setup
loginW = Tk()

# Password Authentication Function
def Authentication():

    valid = 'pythonprogramming'

    if (pwordE = valid):
        # Syntax Error for the above line
        mp = Tk()
        loginW.destroy()
        # Main Program here
        mp.mainloop()

    else:
        errorW = Tk()
        errorL = Label(errorW, text='Invalid Password!')

        errorW.mainloop()

pwordL = Label(loginW, text='Password: ')
pwordE = Entry(loginW, show='*')

logBtn = Button(loginW, text='Login')
logBtn.bind("<Button-1>", Authentication)

pwordL.pack(row=0)
pwordE.pack(row=0, column=1)
logBtn.pack(row=1, columnspan=2)

loginW.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several errors:

- Change `pack` to `grid`.
- change `pwordE = valid` to `pwordE.get() == valid`
- add argument `event` to `Authentication` function

---

complete code:

```
# Login Setup
loginW = Tk()

# Password Authentication Function
def Authentication(event):

    valid = 'pythonprogramming'

    if pwordE.get() == valid:
        # Syntax Error for the above line
        mp = Tk()
        loginW.destroy()
        # Main Program here
        mp.mainloop()

    else:
        errorW = Tk()
        errorL = Label(errorW, text='Invalid Password!')
        errorL.grid(row=0, column=0)
        errorW.mainloop()

pwordL = Label(loginW, text='Password: ')
pwordE = Entry(loginW, show='*')

logBtn = Button(loginW, text='Login')
logBtn.bind("<Button-1>", Authentication)

pwordL.grid(row=0, column=0)
pwordE.grid(row=0, column=1)
logBtn.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

loginW.mainloop()
```

Screenshots:

[image]

Correct Password:

[image]

Incorrect Password:

[image]